# Reading Input File and Putting It Into An Array with Space Delimiter in Perl

Tags: perl, input, delimiter, argv

I am trying to take an input file with `@ARGV` array and write it's all elements to an Array with delimiter space in perl.

sample input parameter is a txt file for example:

```
0145 2145
4578 47896
45 78841
1249 24873
```

(there are multiple of lines but here it is not shown)
the problem is:

1. I do not know how to take for example ARG[0] to an array
2. I want to take every string of that inputfile as single strings in other words the line1 0145 2145 will not be a string it will be two distinct string by delimiting with space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The `@resultarray` in this code will end up holding a list of digits.

If you're giving your program a file name to use as input from the command line, take it off the ARGV array and open it as a filehandle:

```
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(my $filehandle, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open $filename\n";
```

Once you have the filehandle you can loop over each line of the file using a while loop. `chomp` takes that new line character off the end of each line. Use `split` to split each line up based on whitespace. This returns an array (`@linearray` in my code) containing a list of the numbers within that line. I then `push` my line array on to the end of my `@resultarray`.

```
my @resultarray;
while(my $line = <$filehandle>){
    chomp $line;
    my @linearray = split(" ", $line);
    push(@resultarray, @linearray);
}
```

And remember to add

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

at the top of your perl file to help you if you get any problems in your code.

---

Just to clarify how you can deal with different inputs to your program. The following command:

```
perlfile.pl < inputfile.txt
```

Will take the *contents* of inputfile.txt and pipe it to the `STDIN` filehandle. You can then use this filehandle to access the contents of inputfile.txt

```
while(my $line = <STDIN>){
    # do something with this $line
}
```

But you can also give your program a number of file names to read by placing them after the execution command:

```
perlfile.pl inputfile1.txt inputfile2.txt
```

These file names will be read as strings and placed into the @ARGV array so that the array will look like this:

```
@ARGV:
    [0] => "inputfile1.txt"
    [1] => "inputfile2.txt"
```

Since these are just the names of files, you need to open the file in perl before you access the file's contents. So for inputfile1.txt:

```
my $filename1 = shift(@ARGV);
open(my $filehandle1, '<', $filename1) or die "Can't open $filename1";

while(my $line = <$filehandle1>){
    # do something with this line
}
```

Note how I've used `shift` this time to get the next element within the array @ARGV. See the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) for more details on shift. And also more information on [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Comment: thank you very much but i want to see the elements of array so when i write


foreach $value (@resultarray)
{

print($value);
}

then it gives errors like

global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at c:\users......

how can i print the elements

Comment: and also for your code, the error is

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/asdasdfasfagfq.png/ that

Comment: The error you get when printing is a result of the `use warnings` pragma. It requires you to define all variables with a package name at the beginning. So in your case, you must write `my $value` instead of `$value`. Writing perl code this way is a *very good idea* because you will spend alot less time debugging your programs once you are used to it.

Comment: The other error is because you need to use the command line form `test1.pl inputfile.txt` instead of `test1.pl < inputfile.txt`. Using the `<` on the command line passes the inputfile to the `STDIN` file handle. But perl will also accept string arguments after the execution command. These are what go in the @ARGV array.

Comment: Glad I could help!. I've added a bit more on inputs to your program in the answer in case you needed a bit more clarification. Make sure you understand how each part of the perl program works too :)